# Is it possible to add languages/locales to SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, localization, locale

The contents of `sys.syslanguages` lists several languages/locales, however is it possible to add languages? For example, I'd like to add Australian English and Canadian French.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to modify the contents of the `sys.syslanguages` table in **SQL Server 2005** and above. (in previous versions, the system catalogs were editable)

I assume that you would like to add theses languages/locales for displaying currencies and dates in their corresponding formats. If this is the case, this needs to be handled on the UI side of your application.

You can have either user preferences defined for each user or base it on where the user is located, and display the data in their respective formats.